How can Alexa-triggered Lambda be troubleshooted?
I followed this tutorial for triggering an AWS Lambda from an Alexa skill, but it's not working at all. https://pamphl3t.medium.com/send-a-email-from-your-alexa-with-aws-ses-176a81515680

I set the default region to the Lambda function ARN, and clicked "choose to convert your skill to an Alexa-hosted Skill"
After that, the files in the Alexa Skill Code tab become read-only.


When I go to test the skill, it responds as if the original index.js file is still being used instead of the new file in the lambda. Why is it still using the old index.js file? How do I get it to switch over?

Reviewing the article, I noticed that the author had deleted the optional endpoints. I tried doing that and it did change the test response - now upon invoking the skill, I receive "There was a problem with the requested skill's response". This is still problematic as the my lambda does have handling for the Launch request already.

Some additional guidance wasn't included in the article, possibly due to changes in the UI since the article was published in 2021. The missing steps for me were:

Delete the optional endpoints.
Ensure your Lambda index file extension is .js, NOT the default .mjs

Once I did these and rebuilt the skill and deployed the Lambda, I could see the Lambda index file getting hit as expected.
